# How to zip files without including the folder they are in?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am trying to use zipfile to zip several files together into a single .zip file. The files I need to zip are not in the root folder from which the python script runs, so i have to specify the path when adding a file to the zip. The problem is that I end up with a folder structure in the zip file, i really only want each file and not the folders. so..

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('./tmp/afile.zip', 'w')
zip.write('./tmp/file1.txt')
zip.write('./tmp/items/file2.txt')
```

results in a zip files that extracts to:

```
.
|
|-tmp
|  |file.txt
|  |-items
|  |  file2.txt
```

Is there any way to just add the files to the "root" of the zip file and not creature the folders?

Comment: I think this problem was already on Stackoverflow. If I'm not wrong then you can use `zip.write(filename_to_compress, expected_name_in_zip)`

Comment: @furas if the problem is already on stack, flag this as a duplicate in reference to that question.

Comment: @Laif first I would have to find previous question - I only remeber that I answered it long, long time ago

Comment: @furas > Your profile > answers > ctrl+f "zip"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZIp only contents of directory, exclude parent - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055873/zip-only-contents-of-directory-exclude-parent-python)

Comment: @Laif it was long, long time ago - I don't find it on first page but rather on 20, 30 or maybe 50

Comment: @furas it ws on page 3 haha

Comment: @furas good decision to close, mind if I add my answer to yours to show the usage with pathlib?

Comment: @Laif I expected it was much older question :) If you have intersting answer then add it.

Comment: @furas You had the answer, this question is a duplicate so nobody should answer it

Comment: @furas this works, thanks.  - zip.write(filename_to_compress, expected_name_in_zip)

Answer (score 1):

try with Pathlib which returns a posix object with various attributes.

Also I would caution you about using `zip` as a variable as that's a key function in python

```
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipper = ZipFile('afile.zip', 'w')

files = Path(root).rglob('*.txt') #get all files.
for file in files:
    zipper.write(file,file.name)
```

---

[image]

---

[image]